# Multiplicative maps on C*

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Suppose $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex plane and $\mathbb{C}^{*} = \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.
Let $ \varphi  : \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}  $ be a continuous multiplicative map, i.e., assume that $ \varphi$  satisfies
\begin{equation}
 \varphi(zw) = \varphi(z) \varphi(w) ,~~~~   z, w \in \mathbb{C}^{*}.
\end{equation}
We know that there are an integer $k$ and real numbers $a, t$ such that
 $\varphi(z) = z^{k} |z|^{t} e^{ialn|z|} $, $z \in \mathbb{C}^{*}$.

Now we will remove continuity of $\varphi$ and add another condition.

**Question:** Let $ \varphi  : \mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{*}  $ be a multiplicative map, $\varphi(-1) = -1$ and
\begin{equation}
 \varphi(\frac{z-1+\sqrt{2z^{2}+2}}{z+1}) = \dfrac{\varphi(z)-1+\sqrt{2\varphi(z)^{2}+2}}{\varphi(z)+1}  ,~~~~   z \in \mathbb{C}^{*}\setminus \lbrace -1 \rbrace.
\end{equation}
Can we say $\varphi$ is a continuous map? What is the general form of $\varphi$ in this case?

Comment: How are you defining square roots?  And where does that crazy condition come from?

Comment: Square root is referred to as the principal root. I have got this condition in a research work.